# Susy 2 Debug Grids: possible to change individual grid color?

Tags: susy-compass, susy-sass

When debug grids overlap, I'm having issues visually delineating the individual grids. Is it possible to specify a color?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use debug in your global defaults and set the colour. It's referenced at http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/settings/ go to Global Defaults. I suspect that you could probably add your colour to the show grid statement, though I haven't tried it.

Comment: Yes, you can adjust the color in your settings, and you can pass a different settings-map to each show-grids (or container) mixin you are using.